# Angular 2 bootstrapping code not clear

Tags: angular

i am little familiar with angular1 but not familiar with angular2. so facing problem to understand angular2 code. so guide me with little bit to understand angular2 code.

```
<div>Bootstrapping in Angular 1 using ng-app,</div> <div>

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['userApp']);
});


<div>Bootstrapping in Angular 2,</div> 

import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { UsersComponent } from './product.component';

bootstrap(UserComponent);
```

please tell me the meaning of angular2 bootstrapping code.

Comment: Your using Pre-release version o fAngular 2.0.0. try https://github.com/angular/angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:- **AppComponent.ts**

**First step** describe about Component how you can binding the variable with DOM

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

**Step 2:**

**Second step** will define your module ,Angular2 is construct with modularity that means application made up with constructing the modules

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Step 3:**

**Third step** where your application get start ,Bootstrapping is an essential process in Angular - it is where the application is loaded when Angular comes to life.
Bootstrapping Angular applications is certainly different from Angular 1.x, but is still a straightforward procedure. Let's take a look at how this is done.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

reference form https://angular-2-trainingbook.rangle.io/handout/bootstrapping/

Comment: this link is broken u shared "https://angular-2-trainingbook.rangle.io/handout/bootstrapping/"

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/bootstrapping/ . and this one also this is great from official website https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html